# Why does this error occurs while importing through data.sql file "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm setting up a spring-boot+hibernate project. I've created a model class "People" and after running the project h2-console created a table "people" as expected. Then I created a data.sql file in the resource folder and added an import statement to the table. After that the program isn't working and showing the following error.

```
Hibernate: 

    create table people (
       id bigint not null,
        age integer not null,
        job varchar(255),
        name varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
2019-10-16 15:41:34.911  INFO 7540 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@fe09383'
2019-10-16 15:41:34.916  INFO 7540 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-16 15:41:34.963  WARN 7540 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Azad/Workspaces/intellij/home-api/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon"); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "Robi" not found; SQL statement:
insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon") [42122-199]
2019-10-16 15:41:34.964  INFO 7540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-16 15:41:34.966  INFO 7540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Shutdown completed.
2019-10-16 15:41:34.969  INFO 7540 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-16 15:41:34.986  INFO 7540 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-16 15:41:35.002 ERROR 7540 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Azad/Workspaces/intellij/home-api/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon"); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "Robi" not found; SQL statement:
insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon") [42122-199]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.azad.practice.homeapi.HomeApiApplication.main(HomeApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Azad/Workspaces/intellij/home-api/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon"); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "Robi" not found; SQL statement:
insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon") [42122-199]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:509) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:239) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:89) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "Robi" not found; SQL statement:
insert into people (id, age, job, name) values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon") [42122-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.getColumnException(ExpressionColumn.java:176) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:158) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.prepare(Insert.java:322) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:565) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1292) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:217) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:488) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have googled the problem found some solutions on stackoverflow.com but none of them worked for me.

class name: com.azad.practice.homeapi.model.People

```
@Entity
@Table
public class People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private int age;
    private String job;

    protected People() {
    }

    public People(String name, int age, String job) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", job='" + job + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

data.sql

```
insert into people (id, age, job, name)
values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon");
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=debug
spring.datasource.name=testdb
```

I expect that the import statement will work and I will see the data in people table in h2-console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe change `"` to `'`:

`values (1001, 26, "Robi", "Shawon");`

to

`values (1001, 26, 'Robi', 'Shawon');`

I think the problem is about your sql script is not in correct syntax